# Strange behavior of background music in cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d v2 and experiencing a very strange behaviour.

I have a couple of audio tracks which are supposed to be played as background music one after another. But I noticed when these tracks are playing in background, any updates on screen (rendering) isn't working.

For instance I added a new sprite marker after every new track but nothing shown on screen until all the tracks are done playing. I also tried displaying track # using CCLABELBMFont but that also didn't show anything on screen until all tracks are finished playing.

Here's the code:

```
NSString *keyString;
CCARRAY_FOREACH([[GameManager sharedGameManager] _musicItems], keyString){
    if ([[[GameManager sharedGameManager] _soundEngine] isBackgroundMusicPlaying]) {
        int waitCycles = 0;
        while (waitCycles < AUDIO_MAX_WAITTIME) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1f];
            if (![[[GameManager sharedGameManager] _soundEngine] isBackgroundMusicPlaying]) {
                break;
            }
            waitCycles += 1;
        }
    }

    //play sound file
    CCLOG(@"Playing Sound file: %@", keyString);
    [[GameManager sharedGameManager] playBackgroundTrack:keyString];

    **EDIT:**
    /******** changed to include dispatch: start *********/
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CCLOG(@"on main thread");
        CCSprite *marker = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"marker.png"];
        [marker setPosition:ccp(100 * count, 200)];
        [self addChild:marker z:100];
    });
    /***************** end **********************/


}
```

**EDIT:
Here's implementation for audio setup**

```
-(void)setupAudioEngine{
    if(_hasAudioBeenInitialized){
        return; //sound engine already initialized
    }
    else{
        _hasAudioBeenInitialized = YES;
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue new] autorelease];
        NSInvocationOperation *asyncSetupOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                    selector:@selector(initAudioAsync) object:nil];
        [queue addOperation:asyncSetupOperation];
        [asyncSetupOperation autorelease];
    }
}

-(void)initAudioAsync{
    //Initialize audio engine asynchronously
    CCLOG(@"Audio Manager Initializing");
    _managerSoundState = kAudioManagerInitializing;

    //start audio engine
    [CDSoundEngine setMixerSampleRate:CD_SAMPLE_RATE_HIGH];

    //Init audio manager asynchronously as it can take a few seconds
    //The kAMM_FxPlusMusic mode ensure only this game plays audio
    [CDAudioManager initAsynchronously:kAMM_FxPlusMusic];

    //wait for audio manager to initialize
    while ([CDAudioManager sharedManagerState] != kAMStateInitialised) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }

    CDAudioManager *audioManager = [CDAudioManager sharedManager];
    if (audioManager.soundEngine == nil || audioManager.soundEngine.functioning == NO) {
        CCLOG(@"COCOS Dension failed to init. No audio will play");
        _managerSoundState = kAudioManagerFailed;
    }
    else{
        [audioManager setResignBehavior:kAMRBStopPlay autoHandle:YES];
        _soundEngine = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
        _managerSoundState = kAudioManagerReady;
        CCLOG(@"COCOS Dension is ready now");
    }
}
```

Anyone has ideas why it's happening?

Comment: Is this running on the main thread?

Comment: Yes audio is asynchronously loaded and played in background so there's a different thread for it. Is there a way to handle it with 2 threads?

Answer (score 0):

Your sprites are never drawn, because you are blocking the main thread. You should dispatch asynchronously to a background queue and when you want to make changes to the UI (adding or manipulating sprites) dispatch back to the main queue.

Comment: I think you are right. My implementation isn't correct. But when I tried using dispatch_async or NSOperationQueue, it didn't help. May be I am not doing it right way. I added changes above to be displayed in nice format :) . Please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your time and help :D